# Futures passed by reference have different hashcode, compare to false

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having an hard time comparing Futures correctly in Dart. I hope I can be clear enough. I am doing two experiments:

This first test works. I create a future and then assign the same future to another variable. The Future is passed by reference so the variable is pointing at the same memory area and the objects are the same. Indeed the hashcode is the same and the comparison is true.

```dart
  void main() {
     Future f1 = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
     Future f2 = f1;
     print(f1.hashCode);
     print(f2.hashCode);
     print(f1 == f2);
   }
```

Now, in this second test, I am doing the same operation but this time inside a method. I am trying to avoid to sending multiple calls to an API. I do one call and save the Future in a variable. When a method tries to send the request again, I pass him the pending Future instead of creating a new one.
In my mind, since the Futures are passed as a reference, they should still be the same and compare to true. Instead, I get false, and the Hashcode are completely different.

```dart
   void main() {
     Test();
   }
   
   
   class Test {
     
     Future? _future = null;
   
     Test() {
      init();
     }
   
     void init() {
       print("CALL 1");
       Future d1 = processFuture();
       print("ISNULL? "+(_future == null).toString());
       print("CALL 2");
       Future d2 = processFuture();
       print("ISNULL? "+(_future == null).toString());
       print(d1.hashCode);
       print(d2.hashCode);
       print(d1 == d2);
     }
   
     Future processFuture() async {
         print("CALLED processFuture()");
       if (_future != null){
         print("FUTURE IS ALREADY THERE");
         return _future;
       }
       print("NEW FUTURE REQUESTED");
       _future = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
       print("NEW FUTURE CREATED");
       await _future;
       print("FUTURE COMPLETE");
       _future = null;
       print("FUTURE IS NOW NULL");
       return;
     }
     
   }
```

Am I missing something? Can someone explain me what I am misunderstanding and what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: if you want it to work your `processFuture` method cannot be `async`

Comment: @pskink it does work if the function is not async and I return a future with .then(), but I do not understand why.

Comment: ok so it's like nesting two Futures?

Comment: @g.imtech Instead of editing the question with a solution you can post an answer yourself and accept it. It's even recommended so others can see this has an accepted answer.

Comment: Done, but I need to wait for tomorrow to accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactored the function to not be an async function, thanks @pskink

```
void main() {
 Test();
}


class Test {
  
  Future<dynamic>? _future = null;

  Test() {
   init();
  }

  void init() {
    print("CALL 1");
    Future<dynamic>? d1 = processFuture();
    print("ISNULL? "+(_future == null).toString());
    print("CALL 2");
    Future<dynamic>? d2 = processFuture();
    print("ISNULL? "+(_future == null).toString());
    print(d1.hashCode);
    print(d2.hashCode);
    print(d1 == d2);
  }

  Future<dynamic>? processFuture() {
      print("CALLED processFuture()");
    if (_future != null){
      print("FUTURE IS THERE");
      return _future;
    }
    print("NEW FUTURE REQUESTED");
    _future = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1))
    .then((res) {
      print("FUTURE COMPLETE");
      _future = null;
      print("FUTURE IS NOW NULL");
      return res;
    });
    print("NEW FUTURE CREATED");
    return _future;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A function marked with `async` implicitly returns new `Future` instances:

```dart
Future<int> foo() async => 42;
```

is implicitly equivalent to:

```dart
Future<int> foo() => Future.value(42);
```

If an `async` function internally returns a `Future`, then that `Future` is implicitly `await`ed, and its result is returned in a new `Future`.  That is:

```dart
Future<int> bar() async => foo();
```

is implicitly equivalent to:

```dart
Future<int> bar() async => await foo();
```

so `bar()` returns a different `Future` than what `foo()` returned.